# Is it possible to integrate functionbeat with AWS elasticsearch service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm trying to integrate AWS Elasticsearch Service with Functionbeat follow a lot of documents:
https://blog.9fin.com/post/never-miss-a-beat-central-lambda-logging/
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/functionbeat-installation-configuration.html

I have a lot of problem like template can not upload to ES because of port, Credentials need for functionbeat can not acchieve in ES because of role and policy,...

So can anybody tell me if anyone has success in this way? Cause after few days, I read that functionbeat can not integrate with AWS ES.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/functionbeat-with-aws-elasticsearch-service/181712

Answer (score 3):

While all other Beats can work with the OSS version of Elasticsearch, [Functionbeat is only available with a BASIC license](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) of Elasticsearch and the AWS managed ES service doesn't provide that kind of licensing.

Instead, you should consider migrating to ES Cloud or any other on-premise ES deployment.

[image: Elastic subscriptions]

**Update:**

As mentioned by @kontinuity, Functionbeat started shipping with the  OSS version recently.

[image: Elastic subscriptions]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just need to confirm so that I won't spend my time on that

Comment: So, anything else needed regarding this topic?

Comment: At dadoonet comment, I will try to use the official service but it won't take much time. 
Now I'm using the old flow: Lambda -> Cloudwatch Logs -> Kinesis -> Firehose -> Lambda -> S3 -> Logstash ->  Elasticsearch -> Kibana and will customize the Lambda to remove S3 and Logstash for optimize. Hope it work

Comment: As of 2022, FunctionBeat is available under OSS

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I'm working at Elastic.

Adding to Val's great answer that you can look at https://www.elastic.co/cloud and https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01N6YCISK ?

Cloud by elastic is one way to have access to all features, all managed by us. Think about what is there yet like Security, Monitoring, Reporting, SQL, Canvas, Maps UI, Alerting and built-in solutions named Observability, Security, Enterprise Search and what is coming next :) ...

Comment: Thanks for your information :) 
I am looking for a solution so that my flow logs is Lambda -> Cloudwatch Logs -> Kinesis -> functionbeat -> Elasticsearch -> Kibana. Now it's impossible to use AWS Elasticsearch. So do you think with "Elasticsearch Service on Elastic Cloud", can I finish it?

Comment: I think so. If you go to cloud.elastic.co (not through the AWS marketplace), you can try for 14days for free without a credit card. Just give it a try ;)

Comment: Hi dadoonet, thanks for your reply. I has replace functionbeat with a Lambda function doing the same work and it worked. 
Btw, thanks for your support :D

Comment: @AshBlake where did you get the lambda function from? I'm currently trying to get this to work myself, with Cloudwatch -> lambda (functionbeat function) -> elasticservice service trial, and having trouble with the middle part.. the documentation doesn't seem to tell you what you actually put in the lambda function, or am i reading it wrong and you need actually to export the function from your computer?

Comment: Hi @JoshuaD'Alton , actually, I using this flow: Lambda -> Cloudwatch Logs -> Kinesis -> Firehose -> Lambda -> S3 -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch -> Kibana.

AWS Lambda have its template to transform data. What I did is customize it